# Guava Sets.intersection bad performance

Tags: java, performance, collections, set, guava

I've encountered a strange problem in production today. Though I love Guava, I ran into a use case where Guava's `Sets.intersection()` was performing pretty badly. I've written a sample code:

```
Set<Long> cache = new HashSet<>();
for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    cache.add(i);
}
Set<Long> keys = new HashSet<>();
for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    keys.add(i);
}
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Set<Long> foundKeys = new HashSet<>();
for (Long key : keys) {
    if (cache.contains(key)) {
        foundKeys.add(key);
    }
}
System.out.println("Java search: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
SetView<Long> intersection = Sets.intersection(keys, cache);
System.out.println("Guava search: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

I've tried to create a similar production scenario where I've a keys cache, and I'm looking for all the keys present in the cache. Strangely, Guava search is taking a lot longer than Java search. After running this I got:

```
Java search: 0
Guava search: 36
```

Can anyone tell why this isn't suited for my use case or is there a bug in Guava?

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Yes, the Guava implementation happens to be asymmetric: if the first set is a lot bigger than the second one, it is a lot slower. Try switching the two sets.

Comment: Yes, my first set is already much smaller.

Comment: @Mr.White In that case see the first comment :)

Comment: Yes, that helped. I wonder why I'm getting it in production on regular basis then. May be there is something else going on. I'll check further and post.

Comment: @Mr.White What could happen in production that we can't see here is that `size()` is being called often on the set. Since the intersection set returned is just a live view of the two underlying sets, `size()` is recalculated every time it is called. For similar reasons the two original sets aren't garbage collected while the view is live, which can lead to significant slow-down if your system is under heavy load. But these are just guesses really, you should attach a profiler to your running instance of the full application to gather some real-life data.

Comment: That was pretty brilliant. Thanks for your help. size() was causing all the trouble. Even though the size was pretty small.

Comment: @biziclop Would you mind explaining size performance in a bit detail as an answer. I wanted to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out the problem was multiple calls to `SetView.size()`. As `SetView` is a (live) view of the intersection of the two sets, the intersection size needs to be recalculated every time.

```
public static <E> SetView<E> intersection( final Set<E> set1, final Set<?> set2) {
//...
  return new SetView<E>() {
    @Override public Iterator<E> iterator() {
      return Iterators.filter(set1.iterator(), inSet2);
    }
    @Override public int size() {
      return Iterators.size(iterator());
    }
    //...
  };
}
```

As can be seen here, what recalculation means in this case is iterating across the entire view, which can be quite time-consuming.

The way to get around this is therefore either to make sure `size()` is only called once and the value is stored (if you know the underlying sets won't change), or if that isn't possible, create a copy of the intersection via `ImmutableSet.copyOf()` (for example).

Comment: If the first set  we pass is bigger, then only we are having  trouble with size(), otherwise it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Note that `SetView` itself has an `immutableCopy()` method that returns an `ImmutableSet`.

Comment: @ColinD Hmm, I didn't know that, sounds useful. Thanks for the tip.