# Fastest way to convert Guava Sets to List

Tags: java, list, optimization, set, guava

I'm not even sure if this is possible but I'm doing a Set operation like `union` or `intersection` and I need to convert that to a `List` in order to shuffle the list and pass that to a different method that accepts a `List` instead of a `Set`. So I convert the result to a `List` and all is good. But then from the profiler, I see that the operation is taking a long time under load and it's because of the way Guava Sets `.size()` does. It's not a constant operation like normal java Set.

Here's the code example

```java
    @Test
    void testSet() {
        Set<Character> first = ImmutableSet.of('a', 'b', 'c');
        Set<Character> second = ImmutableSet.of('b', 'c', 'd');

        Set<Character> union = Sets.union(first, second);

        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>(union);
    }
```

I'm trying to find the fastest way to convert a Guava `Sets` to a `List`. From digging through the code this is what Guava Sets does https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#L694. It's not a constant operation and it hurts the performance under high load. I'm guessing that `.size` call is from when Java wants to copy a new Collection to a new List it has to know the size to create a List.

Comment: _"taking a long time under load "_ - How do you know? What do you mean by _"a long time"_?  What do you mean by _"under load"_?  These are all very vague metrics and you might not be interpreting your profiler's output correctly.  That said, I looked at the implementation of `Set#union()` and all I can say is ... wow, disappointing.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373758/guava-sets-intersection-bad-performance

Comment: `ImmutableSet.<Character>builder().addAll(first).addAll(second).build().asList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting "performance under high load" argument aside (I suggest doing proper JMH microbenchmarks if it's really relevant in your use case), `Sets` operations are memory-optimized, so if you're copying the data right away, you may want to try different approaches which don't call size at all.

First, `Sets.union` returns [`SetView<E>`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.SetView.html) which has [`immutableCopy()`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.SetView.html#immutableCopy()), on which then you can call `.asList()` view, returning an immutable list  (feel free to chain all operations together):

```
@Test
public void testSetCopy() {
    Set<Character> first = ImmutableSet.of('a', 'b', 'c');
    Set<Character> second = ImmutableSet.of('b', 'c', 'd');

    Sets.SetView<Character> union = Sets.union(first, second);
    List<Character> characters = union.immutableCopy().asList();

    assertThat(characters).containsOnly('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
}
```

Second, you can also consider using `Set` in the first place, as mentioned by Louis:

```
@Test
public void testMultiset() {
    Set<Character> first = ImmutableSet.of('a', 'b', 'c');
    Set<Character> second = ImmutableSet.of('b', 'c', 'd');

    // here it's ugly but maybe you can collect to set in the first place
    ImmutableMultiset<Character> set = ImmutableSet.<Character>builder()
             .addAll(first)
             .addAll(second)
             .build(); // [a, b, c, d]

    List<Character> characters = set.asList();

    assertThat(characters).containsOnly('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
}
```

That said, YMMV, and again I encourage you to do microbenchmarks before choosing any less readable option.

Comment: Why go via `Multiset` instead of just building a `Set`?  `ImmutableSet.builder()` deduplicates.

Comment: Wow, I over-engineered this, thanks Louis for bringing this up! I'll edit my answer.